# AssertionError: The algorithm only supports <class 'gym.spaces.box.Box'> as action spaces but Box(-1.0, 1.0, (3,), float32) was provided

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

So basically I tried converting this custom gym environment from https://github.com/Gor-Ren/gym-jsbsim to use farama foundation's gymnasium api. This is my repo whih I am working on: https://github.com/sryu1/jsbgym
When I try training the environment with gym-jsbsim, it works, but with the gymnasium environment, I get the error that is in the title... I feel like Lines 234 to 242 in tasks.py are somewhere that causes the problem. the same error appears for all algorithms... If anyone could tell me what I did wrong, it'd be very appreciated!
I tried training the custom environment with stable baselines 3 all algos that support Box and they all get the same error.

This is my ipynb in raw format, if you just open a new ipynb file with notepad then past this in then open again, it should work.

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "id": "7e5a3876",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import jsbsim\n",
    "import gymnasium as gym\n",
    "import jsbgym\n",
    "import os\n",
    "from stable_baselines3 import DDPG\n",
    "from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback\n",
    "from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor\n",
    "from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv, VecFrameStack"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 2,
   "id": "c78d0a36",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "env = gym.make('JSBSim-TurnHeadingControlTask-Cessna172P-Shaping.STANDARD-NoFG-v0')"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 3,
   "id": "17ea6f3e",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "data": {
      "text/plain": [
       "(array([ 5.00000000e+03, -1.52383093e-16,  1.16583160e-16,  2.02536000e+02,\n",
       "        -4.26325641e-14, -7.10542736e-15,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,\n",
       "         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,\n",
       "         0.00000000e+00, -3.72529030e-09, -9.68166768e-15, -1.60633375e+02,\n",
       "         2.99000000e+02]),\n",
       " {})"
      ]
     },
     "execution_count": 3,
     "metadata": {},
     "output_type": "execute_result"
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "env.reset()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 4,
   "id": "60a7ecab",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Total Reward for episode 1 is 24.43895374007404\n",
      "Total Reward for episode 2 is 17.88229242588352\n",
      "Total Reward for episode 3 is 20.844080298653026\n",
      "Total Reward for episode 4 is 23.09412403738447\n",
      "Total Reward for episode 5 is 22.540357474496297\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "for episode in range(1, 6):\n",
    "    obs = env.reset()\n",
    "    done = False\n",
    "    total_reward = 0\n",
    "    while not done:\n",
    "        obs, reward, done, _, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())\n",
    "        total_reward += reward\n",
    "    print(\"Total Reward for episode {} is {}\".format(episode, total_reward))"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 5,
   "id": "d819a741",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "class TrainAndLoggingCallback(BaseCallback):\n",
    "    def __init__(self, check_freq, save_path, verbose=1):\n",
    "        super(TrainAndLoggingCallback, self).__init__(verbose)\n",
    "        self.check_freq = check_freq\n",
    "        self.save_path = save_path\n",
    "\n",
    "    def _init_callback(self):\n",
    "        if self.save_path is not None:\n",
    "            os.makedirs(self.save_path, exist_ok=True)\n",
    "\n",
    "    def _on_step(self):\n",
    "        if self.n_calls % self.check_freq == 0:\n",
    "            model_path = os.path.join(\n",
    "                self.save_path, \"best_model_{}\".format(self.n_calls)\n",
    "            )\n",
    "            self.model.save(model_path)\n",
    "\n",
    "        return True"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 6,
   "id": "a0f962d6",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "CHECKPOINT_DIR = \"./train/\"\n",
    "LOG_DIR = \"./logs/\""
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 7,
   "id": "d2ab0033",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "callback = TrainAndLoggingCallback(check_freq=1000000, save_path=CHECKPOINT_DIR)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 8,
   "id": "ea1fd388",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "ename": "AssertionError",
     "evalue": "The algorithm only supports <class 'gym.spaces.box.Box'> as action spaces but Box(-1.0, 1.0, (3,), float64) was provided",
     "output_type": "error",
     "traceback": [
      "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m",
      "\u001b[1;31mAssertionError\u001b[0m                            Traceback (most recent call last)",
      "\u001b[1;32m~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_17260\\3532872291.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m<module>\u001b[1;34m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m----> 1\u001b[1;33m \u001b[0mmodel\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m \u001b[0mDDPG\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[1;34m\"MlpPolicy\"\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0menv\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0mtensorboard_log\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[0mLOG_DIR\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m",
      "\u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\Noah Ryu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\stable_baselines3\\ddpg\\ddpg.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m__init__\u001b[1;34m(self, policy, env, learning_rate, buffer_size, learning_starts, batch_size, tau, gamma, train_freq, gradient_steps, action_noise, replay_buffer_class, replay_buffer_kwargs, optimize_memory_usage, tensorboard_log, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    103\u001b[0m             \u001b[0mtarget_noise_clip\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[1;36m0.0\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    104\u001b[0m             \u001b[0mtarget_policy_noise\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[1;36m0.1\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 105\u001b[1;33m             \u001b[0m_init_setup_model\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[1;32mFalse\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0;32m    106\u001b[0m         )\n\u001b[0;32m    107\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\Noah Ryu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\stable_baselines3\\td3\\td3.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m__init__\u001b[1;34m(self, policy, env, learning_rate, buffer_size, learning_starts, batch_size, tau, gamma, train_freq, gradient_steps, action_noise, replay_buffer_class, replay_buffer_kwargs, optimize_memory_usage, policy_delay, target_policy_noise, target_noise_clip, tensorboard_log, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    118\u001b[0m             \u001b[0moptimize_memory_usage\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[0moptimize_memory_usage\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    119\u001b[0m             \u001b[0msupported_action_spaces\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[0mspaces\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m.\u001b[0m\u001b[0mBox\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 120\u001b[1;33m             \u001b[0msupport_multi_env\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[1;32mTrue\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0;32m    121\u001b[0m         )\n\u001b[0;32m    122\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\Noah Ryu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\stable_baselines3\\common\\off_policy_algorithm.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m__init__\u001b[1;34m(self, policy, env, learning_rate, buffer_size, learning_starts, batch_size, tau, gamma, train_freq, gradient_steps, action_noise, replay_buffer_class, replay_buffer_kwargs, optimize_memory_usage, policy_kwargs, tensorboard_log, verbose, device, support_multi_env, monitor_wrapper, seed, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, use_sde_at_warmup, sde_support, supported_action_spaces)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    117\u001b[0m             \u001b[0muse_sde\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[0muse_sde\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    118\u001b[0m             \u001b[0msde_sample_freq\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[0msde_sample_freq\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 119\u001b[1;33m             \u001b[0msupported_action_spaces\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[0msupported_action_spaces\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0;32m    120\u001b[0m         )\n\u001b[0;32m    121\u001b[0m         \u001b[0mself\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m.\u001b[0m\u001b[0mbuffer_size\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m \u001b[0mbuffer_size\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\Noah Ryu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\stable_baselines3\\common\\base_class.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m__init__\u001b[1;34m(self, policy, env, learning_rate, policy_kwargs, tensorboard_log, verbose, device, support_multi_env, monitor_wrapper, seed, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, supported_action_spaces)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    171\u001b[0m             \u001b[1;32mif\u001b[0m \u001b[0msupported_action_spaces\u001b[0m \u001b[1;32mis\u001b[0m \u001b[1;32mnot\u001b[0m \u001b[1;32mNone\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m:\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    172\u001b[0m                 assert isinstance(self.action_space, supported_action_spaces), (\n\u001b[1;32m--> 173\u001b[1;33m                     \u001b[1;34mf\"The algorithm only supports {supported_action_spaces} as action spaces \"\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0;32m    174\u001b[0m                     \u001b[1;34mf\"but {self.action_space} was provided\"\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    175\u001b[0m                 )\n",
      "\u001b[1;31mAssertionError\u001b[0m: The algorithm only supports <class 'gym.spaces.box.Box'> as action spaces but Box(-1.0, 1.0, (3,), float64) was provided"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "model = DDPG(\"MlpPolicy\", env, tensorboard_log=LOG_DIR)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 9,
   "id": "b80a3ed4",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "ename": "NameError",
     "evalue": "name 'model' is not defined",
     "output_type": "error",
     "traceback": [
      "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m",
      "\u001b[1;31mNameError\u001b[0m                                 Traceback (most recent call last)",
      "\u001b[1;32m~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_17260\\1190813584.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m<module>\u001b[1;34m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m----> 1\u001b[1;33m \u001b[0mmodel\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m.\u001b[0m\u001b[0mlearn\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[0mtotal_timesteps\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[1;36m10000000\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0mcallback\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m\u001b[0mcallback\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0;32m      2\u001b[0m \u001b[0mmodel\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m.\u001b[0m\u001b[0msave\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[1;34m\"JSBSim_10000000_steps\"\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;31mNameError\u001b[0m: name 'model' is not defined"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "model.learn(total_timesteps=10000000, callback=callback)\n",
    "model.save(\"JSBSim_10000000_steps\")"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 10,
   "id": "72842db2",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "ename": "NameError",
     "evalue": "name 'model' is not defined",
     "output_type": "error",
     "traceback": [
      "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m",
      "\u001b[1;31mNameError\u001b[0m                                 Traceback (most recent call last)",
      "\u001b[1;32m~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_17260\\4222837208.py\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m<module>\u001b[1;34m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m      4\u001b[0m     \u001b[0mtotal_reward\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m \u001b[1;36m0\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m      5\u001b[0m     \u001b[1;32mwhile\u001b[0m \u001b[1;32mnot\u001b[0m \u001b[0mdone\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m:\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m----> 6\u001b[1;33m         \u001b[0maction\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0m_\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m \u001b[0mmodel\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m.\u001b[0m\u001b[0mpredict\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[0mobs\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[0;32m      7\u001b[0m         \u001b[0mobs\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0mreward\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0mdone\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m,\u001b[0m \u001b[0minfo\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m=\u001b[0m \u001b[0menv\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m.\u001b[0m\u001b[0mstep\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[0mint\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m(\u001b[0m\u001b[0maction\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m)\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m      8\u001b[0m         \u001b[0mtotal_reward\u001b[0m \u001b[1;33m+=\u001b[0m \u001b[0mreward\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[1;33m\u001b[0m\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;31mNameError\u001b[0m: name 'model' is not defined"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "for episode in range(5):\n",
    "    obs = env.reset()\n",
    "    done = False\n",
    "    total_reward = 0\n",
    "    while not done:\n",
    "        action, _ = model.predict(obs)\n",
    "        obs, reward, done, info = env.step(int(action))\n",
    "        total_reward += reward\n",
    "    print(\"Total Reward for episode {} is {}\".format(episode, total_reward))"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "id": "f0daa1ab",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.7.9"
  },
  "vscode": {
   "interpreter": {
    "hash": "fc676d0716d313b34d9b58671be5ff89ed5ca710c84a0894db60f3144580aba8"
   }
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 5
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Stable Baselines 3](https://Stable%20Baselines%203), at least up to `1.7.0`, depends on `gym`, not on its newer `gymnasium` equivalent.

Although `import gymnasium as gym` should do the trick within your own code, some of the Stable Baselines3 code still performs imports such as (see [td3.py](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/v1.7.0/stable_baselines3/td3/td3.py#L5) for instance):

```
from gym import spaces
```

and uses the `gym` spaces to validate your `gymnasium` environment's action space.

You can check yourself by running `type(env.action_space)`, you'll see that it returns `gymnasium.spaces.box.Box` instead of `gym.spaces.box.Box`.

You can read the comments on [this PR](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/pull/780) to have more details on the potential future solutions.

Comment: Thank you! Eventually I did find out that the problem was that stable baselines3 does not support gym 26.0+ or the gymnasium interface. https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/pull/780